# CTE error: "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am executing the following statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    1 as rn, 
    'name1' as nm
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    rn + 1,
    nm = 'name' + CAST((rn + 1) as varchar(255))
  FROM cte a WHERE rn < 10)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

...which finishes with the error...

```
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "nm" of recursive query "cte".
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Exactly what it says:

`'name1'` has a different data type to `'name' + CAST((rn+1) as varchar(255))`

Try this (untested)

```
;with cte as
(
select 1 as rn, CAST('name1' as varchar(259)) as nm
union all
select rn+1,nm = 'name' + CAST((rn+1) as varchar(255))
from cte a where rn<10)
select * from cte
```

Basically, you have to ensure the length matches too. For the recursive bit, you may have to use `CAST('name' AS varchar(4))` if it fails again

Comment: Sir, that is what just I did.

CAST(1 as varchar(255))

Comment: once again Stackoverflow has answered my question before I ask it. Thanks @priyanka & @gbn

Comment: Just in case, if you still get that error, you should also make sure that the collation of your database, and the collation of your table are the same. In other words, collations should be the same in CTE recursive queries.

Answer (score 29):

You need to cast both nm fields

```
;with cte as
(
select  1 as rn, 
        CAST('name1' AS VARCHAR(255)) as nm
union all
select  rn+1,
        nm = CAST('name' + CAST((rn+1) as varchar(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
from cte a where rn<10)
select * from cte
```

Comment: that is what just I did. CAST(1 as varchar(255)) . A silly mistake forgot to cast.(:

Comment: after fighting with sql, i ended up converting both to decimal and it fixed my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 12):

For me problem was in different collation.

Only this helped me:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS rn, 
    CAST('name1' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS nm
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    rn + 1,
    nm = CAST('name' + CAST((rn + 1) AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS NVARCHAR(4000)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
  FROM cte a WHERE rn < 10)
SELECT * 
FROM cte;
```

Hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

```
;with cte as
(
select 1 as rn, 'name' + CAST(1 as varchar(255)) as nm
union all
select rn+1,nm = 'name' + CAST((rn+1) as varchar(255))
from cte a where rn<10)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Your answer is just like the others, you could edit one of them and delete this. Future readers like me will thank you for the clarity ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I messed up the sequence of columns in top and bottom clauses of `UNION ALL`. And it turned out that a `varchar` column appeared 'under' an `int` one. An easy mistake to make of you have lots of columns

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! this was the solution that worked for me. a very easy overlook

Answer (score 1):

If you use CONCAT in the recursive term of a rcte, since the output type of concat is varchar(MAX), you only need to cast the column in the initial query:

```
WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS nr, CAST('1' AS varchar(MAX)) AS trail
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nr+1, CONCAT(trail, '/', nr+1)
    FROM rcte
    WHERE nr < 5
)
SELECT * FROM rcte;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using nvarchar(max)

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT x,x_name FROM (VALUES (1,CAST('' AS nvarchar(MAX)))) AS     test(x,x_name)
UNION ALL
SELECT x + 1 x, CONCAT(x_name,x+1)  FROM CTE WHERE x < 10 )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS nr, CAST('1' AS varchar(MAX)) AS trail
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nr+1, cast(CONCAT(trail, '/', nr+1) as varchar(max))
    FROM rcte
    WHERE nr < 5
)
SELECT * FROM rcte;
```

Comment: Instead of posting Code only answer, please explain the context how this answer will help..

Comment: This will give above output without any error. as if you will execute above query it will give you error in sql. hence I have used cast function to make it error free

Answer (score -4):

```
;with tmp1(NewsId,DataItem ,HeaderText)
 as
  (

    select NewsId, LEFT(HeaderText, CHARINDEX(',',HeaderText+',')-1),
    STUFF(HeaderText, 1, CHARINDEX(',',HeaderText+','), '') 
    from Currentnews

    union all

    select NewsId, LEFT(HeaderText, CHARINDEX(',',HeaderText+',')-1),
    STUFF(HeaderText, 1, CHARINDEX(',',HeaderText+','), '')
    from tmp1
    where HeaderText > ''

   )

   select NewsId, DataItem
   from tmp1
   order by NewsId
```

Comment: This is impossible to read without proper formatting. See [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Probably he is a newbie (: I was also at one time

Comment: I've been using the exact query you provided and it still gives me the same error as question states.