# Query to get only numbers from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

```
string 1: 003Preliminary Examination Plan   
string 2: Coordination005  
string 3: Balance1000sheet
```

The output I expect is

```
string 1: 003
string 2: 005
string 3: 1000
```

And I want to implement it in SQL.

Comment: so you want to make a select and extrac the numbers from the values after ":" ?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

First create this **`UDF`**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(
  @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @intAlpha INT
  SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
  BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
      SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
  END
  RETURN LEN(COALESCE(TRIM(CAST(ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0) AS INT)),0))>0 then COALESCE(TRIM(CAST(ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0) AS INT)),0) else 0 end
END
GO
```

Now use the **`function`** as

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(column_name) 
from table_name
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45f11/2)**

I hope this solved your problem.

**[Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/)**

**4/10/23 - Modified Return Statement based on comments**

Comment: This works, although it extracts and concatenates ALL numbers from the string, so e.g. /p-1544937/apartment-flat-6th-october.html will return 15449376, which is not always what you may be looking for

Comment: Here is the source http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/

Comment: It doesn't handle decimal numbers. For example input of '10.95' will return '1095'

Comment: It should really return an INT. `RETURN CAST(ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0) AS INT)`

Comment: @stomy that will blow up with a nice overflow error given an all-numeric 255-character string though (less than that too, actually).

Comment: How to do it without creating a function? For example I just want to use a select query and use inbuilt functions?

Comment: Thanks for help. Just wanted to modify the return statement.
' RETURN case when LEN(COALESCE(TRIM(@strAlphaNumeric),0))>0 then COALESCE(TRIM(@strAlphaNumeric),0) else 0 end '

Comment: The latest update broke the query - it doesn't include `CASE WHEN`, and `TRIM` won't work on something that's been cast as an INT. Not sure what value it was intending to add. @stomy I disagree that it should return an INT since the OP expected the solution to return answers with leading 0s like 003 and 005.

Answer (score 66):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      string NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
    ('003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    ('Coordination005'),
    ('Balance1000sheet')

SELECT LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1) 
FROM (
    SELECT subsrt = SUBSTRING(string, pos, LEN(string))
    FROM (
        SELECT string, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string)
        FROM @temp
    ) d
) t
```

**Output:**

```
----------
003
005
1000
```

Comment: While I am impressed with this answer and it perfectly addresses the OP's question, it should be noted that this solution will only work for contiguous series of numbers.  For a string like `Coor60nation005`, it will return `60` and not the ending `005`

Comment: +1 to this answer and to Baodad's comment, because this is precisely the behavior I was searching for but the accepted answer was not.

Comment: It does not work for (111) 222-3333.   I want 1112223333

Comment: What if the string starts with numbers and then characters and then again numbers?
For example: '123abc$%10xyz9'.
How can I get '123109' as the result with a select statement?

Answer (score 28):

Query:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    string NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
    ('003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    ('Coordination005'),
    ('Balance1000sheet')

SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    string) + 1) AS Number
FROM @temp
```

Comment: this does not work with white space or separated numbers, but answers the question.

Comment: What is with the "string + 't' " ?

Comment: @Vnge I guess to make sure that string ends with a letter

Comment: @Vnge without adding any character at the end ('t' or any thing) , the case Coordination005 will be failed

Answer (score 24):

Please try:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)='Balance1000sheet'

SELECT LEFT(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Val+'a')-1) from(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@var, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @var), LEN(@var)) Val
)x
```

Comment: **`declare @var nvarchar(max)='Balance1000sheet123'

SELECT LEFT(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Val+'a')-1) from(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@var, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @var), LEN(@var)) Val
)x`**. What is the numeric is not in continuous.

Comment: It will give the first numeric in the string. i.e. 1000

Comment: YES THE CASE MAY BE Balance1000sheet123 AS WELL

Comment: I put this code in a scalar function because i had to sort by number part only of an alphanumeric. Worked great! 

select alpha_column, * from TableA
order by dbo.fn_extract_number_from_alphanumeric (alpha_column) ;

Answer (score 12):

I found this approach works about 3x faster than the top voted answer. Create the following function, dbo.GetNumbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNumbers(@String VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN;
    WITH
        Numbers
    AS (
        --Step 1.
        --Get a column of numbers to represent
        --every character position in the @String.
        SELECT 1 AS Number
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Number + 1
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE Number < LEN(@String)
        )
        ,Characters
    AS (
        SELECT Character
        FROM Numbers
        CROSS APPLY (
                --Step 2.
                --Use the column of numbers generated above
                --to tell substring which character to extract.
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, Number, 1) AS Character
            ) AS c
        )
    --Step 3.
    --Pattern match to return only numbers from the CTE
    --and use STRING_AGG to rebuild it into a single string.
    SELECT @String = STRING_AGG(Character,'')
    FROM Characters
    WHERE Character LIKE '[0-9]'

    --allows going past the default maximum of 100 loops in the CTE
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 8000) 

    RETURN @String
END
GO
```

**Testing**

Testing for purpose:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNumbers(InputString) AS Numbers
FROM ( VALUES
         ('003Preliminary Examination Plan') --output: 003
        ,('Coordination005')                 --output: 005
        ,('Balance1000sheet')                --output: 1000
        ,('(111) 222-3333')                  --output: 1112223333
        ,('1.38hello@f00.b4r#\-6')           --output: 1380046
    ) testData(InputString)
```

Testing for performance:
Start off setting up the test data...

```
--Add table to hold test data
CREATE TABLE dbo.NumTest (String VARCHAR(8000)) 

--Make an 8000 character string with mix of numbers and letters
DECLARE @Num VARCHAR(8000) = REPLICATE('12tf56se',800)

--Add this to the test table 500 times
DECLARE @n INT = 0
WHILE @n < 500
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.NumTest VALUES (@Num)
    SET @n = @n +1
END
```

Now testing the dbo.GetNumbers function:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNumbers(NumTest.String) AS Numbers
FROM dbo.NumTest -- Time to complete: 1 min 7s
```

Then testing the UDF from the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667431/11418272) on the same data.

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(NumTest.String)
FROM dbo.NumTest -- Time to complete: 3 mins 12s
```

[Inspiration for dbo.GetNumbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797646)

**Decimals**

If you need it to handle decimals, you can use either of the following approaches, I found no noticeable performance differences between them.

- change `'[0-9]'` to `'[0-9.]'`
- change `Character LIKE '[0-9]'` to `ISNUMERIC(Character) = 1` (SQL treats a single decimal point as "numeric")

**Bonus**

You can easily adapt this to differing requirements by swapping out `WHERE Character LIKE '[0-9]'` with the following options:

- `WHERE Letter LIKE '[a-zA-Z]'     --Get only letters`
- `WHERE Letter LIKE '[0-9a-zA-Z]'  --Remove non-alphanumeric`
- `WHERE Letter LIKE '[^0-9a-zA-Z]' --Get only non-alphanumeric`

Comment: The `STRING_AGG` added by 2017 really makes this a much cleaner piece of code and most likely even faster than the conversion to XML using PATH.  I also used a CTE initially and came searching to see if anyone had a better way of doing it.  Nicely done.

Comment: Added to my lib of awesome SQL functions, and already in use in a good 10+ places across multiple projects.

Answer (score 10):

Getting only numbers from a string can be done in a one-liner.
Try this :

```
SUBSTRING('your-string-here', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'your-string-here'), LEN('your-string-here'))
```

**NB: Only works for the first int in the string, ex: abc123vfg34 returns 123.**

Comment: If you pass the length of the whole string as the 3rd arg, it will take the rest of the string starting from the first digit it finds. Did you try it with your example? It will actually return `123vfg34`

Answer (score 7):

A solution for SQL Server 2017 and later, using [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql):

```sql
DECLARE @T table (string varchar(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT @T 
    (string)
VALUES 
    ('003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    ('Coordination005'),
    ('Balance1000sheet');

SELECT 
    result =
        REPLACE(
            TRANSLATE(
                T.string COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, 
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
                SPACE(26)), 
            SPACE(1), 
            SPACE(0))
FROM @T AS T;
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| 003 |
| 005 |
| 1000 |

The code works by:

1. Replacing characters a-z (ignoring case & accents) with a space
2. Replacing spaces with an empty string.

The string supplied to `TRANSLATE` can be expanded to include additional characters.

Answer (score 4):

With the previous queries I get these results:

**'AAAA1234BBBB3333' >>>> Output: 1234**

**'-çã+0!\aº1234' >>>> Output: 0**

The code below returns All numeric chars:

**1st output: 12343333**

**2nd output: 01234**

```
declare @StringAlphaNum varchar(255)
declare @Character varchar
declare @SizeStringAlfaNumerica int
declare @CountCharacter int

set @StringAlphaNum = 'AAAA1234BBBB3333'
set @SizeStringAlfaNumerica = len(@StringAlphaNum)
set @CountCharacter = 1

while isnumeric(@StringAlphaNum) = 0
begin
    while @CountCharacter < @SizeStringAlfaNumerica
        begin
            if substring(@StringAlphaNum,@CountCharacter,1) not like '[0-9]%'
            begin
                set @Character = substring(@StringAlphaNum,@CountCharacter,1)
                set @StringAlphaNum = replace(@StringAlphaNum, @Character, '')
            end
    set @CountCharacter = @CountCharacter + 1
    end
    set @CountCharacter = 0
end
select @StringAlphaNum
```

Comment: **Beware:** Solutions iterating through each character typically have poor performance in T-SQL. Once I substituted similar loop which was doing simple replacements with built-in `REPLACE()` function and performance went up 5000% (processing became 50 times faster). In other words, this can make your query 50 times slower than it could be. Avoid loops using built-in text processing functions. In worst case, create custom text processing function in .NET and link it to SQL server.

Comment: Nuno, this doesn't quite work. In your WHILE loop, you test if the character is numeric and shorten the string if it is not; however, you neglect to update the `@SizeStringAlfaNumerica`. Otherwise, thanks! :) I'll let you update your code, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @puvodni nvarchar(20)
set @puvodni = N'abc1d8e8ttr987avc'

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @puvodni) > 0 SET @puvodni = REPLACE(@puvodni, SUBSTRING(@puvodni, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @puvodni), 1), '' ) 

SELECT @puvodni
```

Answer (score 3):

This UDF will work for all types of strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_getNumbersFromString (@string varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE  @String like '%[^0-9]%'
    SET    @String = REPLACE(@String, SUBSTRING(@String, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @String), 1), '')
    RETURN @String
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not have rights to create functions but had text like

```
["blahblah012345679"]
```

And needed to extract the numbers out of the middle

Note this assumes the numbers are grouped together and not at the start and end of the string.

```
select substring(column_name,patindex('%[0-9]%', column_name),patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', column_name)-patindex('%[0-9]%', column_name)+1)
from table name
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query does not work with phone numbers like this

+49 1522 662-44-33

It just truncates the string to 49 whereas I would expect

4915226624433

Comment: This worked for me but I can see where there might be a problem if the numbers are broken up.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little modification to @Epsicron 's answer

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    string) + 1) AS Number
FROM (values ('003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    ('Coordination005'),
    ('Balance1000sheet')) as a(string)
```

no need for a temporary variable

Comment: +1 as this worked for me. I actually needed to parse decimal values so changed the patterns to  '%[0-9, .]%'  which means it will select 999.99 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread its the first in google search, I came up with a different answer than what came before. This will allow you to pass your criteria for what to keep within a string, whatever that criteria might be. You can put it in a function to call over and over again if you want.

```
declare @String VARCHAR(MAX) = '-123.  a    456-78(90)'
declare @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255) = '%[0-9]%'
declare @return varchar(max)

WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
    begin
    set @return = CONCAT(@return, SUBSTRING(@string,patindex(@matchexpression, @string),1))
    SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')
    end
select (@return)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly find out the number's starting length then reverse the string to find out the first position again(which will give you end position of number from the end). Now if you deduct 1 from both number and deduct it from string whole length you'll get only number length. Now get the number using SUBSTRING

```
declare @fieldName nvarchar(100)='AAAA1221.121BBBB'

declare @lenSt int=(select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @fieldName)-1)
declare @lenEnd int=(select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@fieldName))-1)

select SUBSTRING(@fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @fieldName), (LEN(@fieldName) - @lenSt -@lenEnd))
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL function to read all the integers from text and return the one at the indicated index, starting from left or right, also using a starting search term (optional):

```
create or alter function dbo.udf_number_from_text(
    @text nvarchar(max),
    @search_term nvarchar(1000) = N'',
    @number_position tinyint = 1,
    @rtl bit = 0
) returns int
as
    begin
        declare @result int = 0;
        declare @search_term_index int = 0;

        if @text is null or len(@text) = 0 goto exit_label;
        set @text = trim(@text);
        if len(@text) = len(@search_term) goto exit_label;

        if len(@search_term) > 0
            begin
                set @search_term_index = charindex(@search_term, @text);
                if @search_term_index = 0 goto exit_label;
            end;

        if @search_term_index > 0
            if @rtl = 0
                set @text = trim(right(@text, len(@text) - @search_term_index - len(@search_term) + 1));
            else
                set @text = trim(left(@text, @search_term_index - 1));
        if len(@text) = 0 goto exit_label;

        declare @patt_number nvarchar(10) = '%[0-9]%';
        declare @patt_not_number nvarchar(10) = '%[^0-9]%';
        declare @number_start int = 1;
        declare @number_end int;
        declare @found_numbers table (id int identity(1,1), val int);

        while @number_start > 0
        begin
            set @number_start = patindex(@patt_number, @text);
            if @number_start > 0
                begin
                    if @number_start = len(@text)
                        begin
                            insert into @found_numbers(val)
                            select cast(substring(@text, @number_start, 1) as int);

                            break;
                        end;
                    else
                        begin
                            set @text = right(@text, len(@text) - @number_start + 1);
                            set @number_end = patindex(@patt_not_number, @text);

                            if @number_end = 0
                                begin
                                    insert into @found_numbers(val)
                                    select cast(@text as int);

                                    break;
                                end;
                            else
                                begin
                                    insert into @found_numbers(val)
                                    select cast(left(@text, @number_end - 1) as int);

                                    if @number_end = len(@text)
                                        break;
                                    else
                                        begin
                                            set @text = trim(right(@text, len(@text) - @number_end));
                                            if len(@text) = 0 break;
                                        end;
                                end;
                        end;
                end;
        end;

        if @rtl = 0
            select @result = coalesce(a.val, 0)
            from (select row_number() over (order by m.id asc) as c_row, m.val
                    from @found_numbers as m) as a
            where a.c_row = @number_position;
        else
            select @result = coalesce(a.val, 0)
            from (select row_number() over (order by m.id desc) as c_row, m.val
                    from @found_numbers as m) as a
            where a.c_row = @number_position;


        exit_label:
            return @result;
    end;
```

Example:

```
select dbo.udf_number_from text(N'Text text 10 text, 25 term', N'term',2,1);
```

returns 10;

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the simplest and easiest one. This will work on the entire String for multiple occurences as well.

```css
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetNumbers(@strInput NVARCHAR(500))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @strOut NVARCHAR(500) = '', @intCounter INT = 1
WHILE @intCounter <= LEN(@strInput) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @strOut = @strOut + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@strInput, @intCounter, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN SUBSTRING(@strInput, @intCounter, 1) ELSE '' END    
    SET @intCounter = @intCounter + 1 

END
RETURN @strOut
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Following a solution using a single common table expression (CTE).

```
DECLARE @s AS TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY, value nvarchar(max));

INSERT INTO @s
VALUES
    (1, N'003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    (2, N'Coordination005'),
    (3, N'Balance1000sheet');

SELECT * FROM @s ORDER BY id;

WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        1 AS i,
        SUBSTRING(value, 1, 1) AS c
    FROM
        @s
    WHERE
        LEN(value) > 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        t.id,
        t.i + 1 AS i,
        SUBSTRING(s.value, t.i + 1, 1) AS c
    FROM
        t
        JOIN @s AS s ON t.id = s.id
    WHERE
        t.i < LEN(s.value)
)
SELECT
    id,
    STRING_AGG(c, N'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i ASC) AS value
FROM
    t
WHERE
    c LIKE '[0-9]'
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @index NVARCHAR(20);
SET @index = 'abd565klaf12';

WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @index) != 0
BEGIN
    SET @index = REPLACE(@index, SUBSTRING(@index, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @index), 1), '');
END

SELECT @index;
```

One can replace `[0-9]` with `[a-z]` if numbers only are wanted with desired castings using the `CAST` function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If we use the User Define Function, the query speed will be greatly reduced. This code extracts the number from the string....

```
        SELECT 
           Reverse(substring(Reverse(rtrim(ltrim( substring([FieldName] , patindex('%[0-9]%', [FieldName] ) , len([FieldName]) )))) , patindex('%[0-9]%', Reverse(rtrim(ltrim( substring([FieldName] , patindex('%[0-9]%', [FieldName] ) , len([FieldName]) )))) ), len(Reverse(rtrim(ltrim( substring([FieldName] , patindex('%[0-9]%', [FieldName] ) , len([FieldName]) ))))) )) NumberValue
        FROM dbo.TableName
```

Comment: This Code execute very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_letters_and_numbers(input_string TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (letters INT, numbers INT) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 
        sum(CASE WHEN input_string ~ '[A-Za-z]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as letters,
        sum(CASE WHEN input_string ~ '[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numbers
    FROM unnest(string_to_array(input_string, '')) as input_string;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution:

```
with SL as (select 0 as STEP,@VALUE as VAL
  union all select STEP+1,replace(VAL,SUBSTRING(VAL,patindex('%[^0-9]%',VAL),1),'') from SL where patindex('%[^0-9]%',VAL)>0)
  select top 1 VAL from SL order by STEP desc
```

It can work if string's length is fitted in `substring` function (8000 for varchar or 4000 for nvarchar) and contains not more than 100 *different* non-numeric characters — upper and lower case is counted or not according to your collation settings.

Answer (score -1):

For the hell of it...

This solution is different to all earlier solutions, viz:

- There is no need to create a function
- There is no need to use pattern matching
- There is no need for a temporary table
- This solution uses a recursive common table expression (CTE)

But first - note the question does not specify where such strings are stored. In my solution below, I create a CTE as a quick and dirty way to put these strings into some kind of "source table".

Note also - this solution uses a [recursive common table expression](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) (CTE) - so don't get confused by the usage of two CTEs here. The first is simply to make the data avaliable to the solution - but it is only the second CTE that is required in order to solve this problem. You can adapt the code to make this second CTE query your existing table, view, etc.

Lastly - my coding is verbose, trying to use column and CTE names that explain what is going on and you might be able to simplify this solution a little. I've added in a few pseudo phone numbers with some (expected and atypical, as the case may be) formatting for the fun of it.

```
with SOURCE_TABLE as (
    select '003Preliminary Examination Plan' as numberString
    union all select 'Coordination005' as numberString
    union all select 'Balance1000sheet' as numberString
    union all select '1300 456 678' as numberString
    union all select '(012) 995 8322  ' as numberString
    union all select '073263 6122,' as numberString
),
FIRST_CHAR_PROCESSED as (
    select
        len(numberString) as currentStringLength,
        isNull(cast(try_cast(replace(left(numberString, 1),' ','z') as tinyint) as nvarchar),'') as firstCharAsNumeric,
        cast(isNull(cast(try_cast(nullIf(left(numberString, 1),'') as tinyint) as nvarchar),'') as nvarchar(4000)) as newString,
        cast(substring(numberString,2,len(numberString)) as nvarchar) as remainingString
    from SOURCE_TABLE
    union all
    select
        len(remainingString) as currentStringLength,
        cast(try_cast(replace(left(remainingString, 1),' ','z') as tinyint) as nvarchar) as firstCharAsNumeric,
        cast(isNull(newString,'') as nvarchar(3999)) + isNull(cast(try_cast(nullIf(left(remainingString, 1),'') as tinyint) as nvarchar(1)),'') as newString,
        substring(remainingString,2,len(remainingString)) as remainingString
    from FIRST_CHAR_PROCESSED fcp2
    where fcp2.currentStringLength > 1
)
select 
    newString
    ,* -- comment this out when required
from FIRST_CHAR_PROCESSED 
where currentStringLength = 1
```

So what's going on here?

Basically in our CTE we are selecting the first character and using `try_cast` ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) to cast it to a `tinyint` (which is a large enough data type for a single-digit numeral). Note that the type-casting rules in SQL Server say that an empty string (or a space, for that matter) will resolve to zero, so the `nullif` is added to force spaces and empty strings to resolve to null ([see discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478423/cast-convert-empty-string-to-int-in-sql-server)) (otherwise our result would include a zero character any time a space is encountered in the source data).

The CTE also returns everything after the first character - and that becomes the input to our recursive call on the CTE; in other words: now let's process the next character.

Lastly, the field `newString` in the CTE is generated (in the second `SELECT`) via concatenation. With recursive CTEs [the data type must match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838276/cte-error-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part) between the two `SELECT` statements for any given column - including the column size. Because we know we are adding (at most) a single character, we are casting that character to nvarchar(1) and we are casting the `newString` (so far) as nvarchar(3999). Concatenated, the result will be nvarchar(4000) - which matches the type casting we carry out in the first `SELECT`.

If you run this query and exclude the `WHERE` clause, you'll get a sense of what's going on - but the rows may be in a strange order. (You won't necessarily see all rows relating to a single input value grouped together - but you should still be able to follow).

Hope it's an interesting option that may help a few people wanting a strictly expression-based solution.

Comment: PS. FWIW I thoughy my bullet points made it clear how this solution is novel. Notably, it uses set logic rather than procedural code and I wonder whether as a result it would provide a performance increase too.

Answer (score -3):

In Oracle

You can get what you want using this:

```
SUBSTR('ABCD1234EFGH',REGEXP_INSTR ('ABCD1234EFGH', '[[:digit:]]'),REGEXP_COUNT ('ABCD1234EFGH', '[[:digit:]]'))
```

Sample Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('003Preliminary Examination Plan  ',REGEXP_INSTR ('003Preliminary Examination Plan  ', '[[:digit:]]'),REGEXP_COUNT ('003Preliminary Examination Plan  ', '[[:digit:]]')) SAMPLE1,
SUBSTR('Coordination005',REGEXP_INSTR ('Coordination005', '[[:digit:]]'),REGEXP_COUNT ('Coordination005', '[[:digit:]]')) SAMPLE2,
SUBSTR('Balance1000sheet',REGEXP_INSTR ('Balance1000sheet', '[[:digit:]]'),REGEXP_COUNT ('Balance1000sheet', '[[:digit:]]')) SAMPLE3 FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are using Postgres and you have data like '2000 - some sample text' then try substring and position combination, otherwise if in your scenario there is no delimiter, you need to write regex:

```
SUBSTRING(Column_name from 0 for POSITION('-' in column_name) - 1) as 
number_column_name
```