# SQL Query/function to remove alphabets only from end

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Need help in creating a function which removes characters(alphabets) only from end or till a number comes at the right.

**For Eg :**

```
select fnStripRightAlpha('ABCD123F') --Should Return 'ABCD123'

select fnStripRightAlpha('PORT123G67KK') --Should Return 'PORT123G67'

select fnStripRightAlpha('123465') --Should Return '123465'

select fnStripRightAlpha('ABCDG') --Should Return ''
```

I [saw functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string) which remove all alphabets, but they do not solve my purpose as only rightmost characters are to be stripped.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only have alphanumeric characters, You can use `PATINDEX` with `STUFF` and `REVERSE` like this.

**Query**

```
SELECT
ISNULL(REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(col),1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(col)) -1,'')),'') as col
FROM
(
    VALUES('ABCD123F'),('PORT123G67KK'),('123465'),('ABCDG')
) as tab(col)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
col
ABCD123
PORT123G67
123465
''
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is

```
    declare @str varchar(100)
set @str='ABCD123F'
select substring(@str,1,len(@str)-patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(@str))+1)
```

Comment: simple but doesn't work for case 2 and 4. returns `PORT123G67K`
and `ABCD`