# mysql - search pattern and replace

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table wp422_posts and I need to manipulate one type of values in post_name column. Actually, I need to manipulate long value beginning with 4 digits (unique ID) and than text, I need to get the 4 digits and left them there. Could anybody help me, please? I'm new to MySQL. Other values - which do not start with 4 digits and dash has to stay same.

one example of value of post_name

- old:
  "2147-sprava-uzivatelskych-uctu-databaze-oracle-v-prostredi-autocad-map-3d"
  desired
- new one: "2147"

How to select correct values in column:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp422_posts` WHERE `post_name` LIKE "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%"
```

it returns empty result, but why?

How to get rid of not needed part?

Thanks relly much for your help.

Comment: You're trying to use a regular expression, but that's not what LIKE does. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that starting part is always 4 digit number and that is only  needed, then you can use this:-

```
SELECT LEFT(COL_NAME, 4) 
FROM `wp422_posts`
```

Then you can use update statement to update the table. Somthing like:-

```
UPDATE `wp422_posts`
SET COL_NAME = LEFT(COL_NAME, 4)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No, the problem is that is not always 4 digit number. I have to change only the ones which are the for numbers.

Comment: then may be this is somthing what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string