# SQL - WHERE between on varchar column

Tags: sql, where-clause, between

I have a table `company` with column `customerID` and I want every customer id from 80000 to 80999.

But the column `customerID` is varchar an some of them contain letters.

So, I must put `customerID` into ' ' and when I try this query:

```
select *
from company
where customerID between '80000' and '80999'
```

it returns also `customerID` 800 for example.

Any ideas how this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where customerID between '80000' and '80999'
  and character_length(customerID) = 5 -- only five digit IDs
```

Comment: thank you - interesting solution, in my case the function would be LEN(customerID) = 5

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to format. Something like this should get you started [Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

If the CustomerID is an integer, which it should, you don't need the quotes around the numnbers. It should solve the problem:

```
select *
from company
where customerID between 80000 and 80999;
```