# CAST/CONVERT empty string to INT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I came across a bug where I was using `CAST(Col1 AS INT) + CAST(Col2 AS INT)` where both Col1 and Col2 are `VARCHAR` and I was getting valid results out when Col1 or Col2 was blank and I didn't expect this. I checked and CAST (and CONVERT) both have this default behavior of replacing blank with 0:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '')
```

I checked the [info page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) and I can't see any reference to explain why this is the behavior (or change it through a server setting). I can of course work around this but I wanted to ask why this is the behavior as I do not think it is intuitive.

I'd actually rather this `CAST` failed or gave `NULL`, is there a server setting somewhere which effects this?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's designed that way.

Comment: It is basic mathematics. An `integer` cannot be **blank**, though in SQL DB it can be `NULL`.

Comment: `'' to 0,  NULL to NULL and 'invalid number' to error`

Comment: I wasn't trying to state that this behaviour in SQL is a bug, it was a bug in our product which led me to find this behaviour and I question whether I can change it because I think this is not intuitive behaviour

Answer (score 22):

Consider an `INT` in SQL Server. It can be one of three values:

- NULL
- 0
- Not 0

So if you're casting/converting an empty string, which you are assuming is a number, then 0 is the most logical value. It allows for a distinction between NULL and 0.

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) -- NULL
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)   -- 0
SELECT CAST('42' AS INT) -- 42
```

I'd say that's logical.

If you did:

```
SELECT CAST('abc' AS INT)
```

You'd get:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.

If you do wish to handle empty strings as `NULL` use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177562.aspx) as [Bogdan suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478738/57475):

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(2) = ''

SELECT CAST(NULLIF(@val,'') AS INT)  -- produces NULL
```

> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

Finally, if your  columns are storing `INT` values, then consider changing its data type to `INT` if you can.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree. 0 is a valid number like so I don't see why it should be treated as a special case and I think an INT is either NULL or a whole number. I think it would be more intuitive for the cast to fail with a blank string because a blank string is not NULL nor is it a valid number. If this is the logical behaviour then why does the same action with the DECIMAL data type produce an error instead of 0?

Comment: even more interesting:
SELECT CAST('true' AS [bit]) -- 1
SELECT CAST('false' AS [bit]) -- 0
SELECT CAST('' AS [bit]) -- 0

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know `NULL` is a marker that indicates that a data value does not exist. And `''` is a value, empty but value.

So MS SQL cast (or converts) empty value into `0` by default. To overcome this and show it as `NULL` you can use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Simple example:

```
SELECT  int_as_varchars as actual,
        cast(NULLIF(int_as_varchars,'') as int) as with_nullif,
        cast(int_as_varchars as int) as just_cast
FROM (VALUES
('1'),
(''),
(NULL),
('0')
) as t(int_as_varchars)
```

Output:

```
actual  with_nullif just_cast
1       1           1
        NULL        0
NULL    NULL        NULL
0       0           0
```

As you see NULLIF in that case will help you to get `NULL` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
declare @t table(bucket bigint);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (0);

declare @Bucket bigint = 0 --filter by 0

select * from @t
where 1=1
AND ((@Bucket is Null or cast(@Bucket as nvarchar) = '') or bucket=@Bucket)
```