# CONVERT works for Empty String to Int, but not for Empty String to Decimal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

In SQL Server, the CONVERT function successfully converts an empty string to integer (0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,'') AS Int
```

However, the CONVERT function fails when converting an empty string to a decimal:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,0),'') AS Decimal
```

Is there a logical reason for this difference in treatment?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478728/1260204

Comment: No, there isn't. And one can easily argue that an empty string should throw the same error. This is how a bug becomes a feature.

Comment: that's the documented behaviour of an empty decimal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#truncating-and-rounding-results.

Comment: @1010, in defense of the OP, "documented" <> "explained", and in this case that's true in spades.