# Convert empty nchar to numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2019.

```
select convert(bigint, ' ')
```

returns `0`

```
select convert(numeric, ' ')
```

returns:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Can anyone tell me why the behaviour between these two datatypes is different? I would have expected, that the second example returns `0` or `0.00`.

Comment: I would, personally, prefer both failed. Neither A zero length string or whitespace are a number. `NULL` would be a much better alternative.

Comment: History and a lack of will from MS to force developers to use good coding practices.

Comment: @Larnu I'd agree, but [there seem to be others that find this behaviour logical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478728/14015737) somehow...

Answer (score 2):

From [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#truncating-and-rounding-results):

"SQL Server also returns an error when an empty string (" ") is converted to `numeric` or `decimal`."

It's the documented behavior, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way it is implemented. Casting an empty string or a string with only spaces to an `INT` data type will result in `0`. [Some people regard this as logical behavior, others don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478728/14015737).

For a `DECIMAL` type, the same cast fails.

However, this is only true for spaces! Trying to cast other whitespace characters like tabs, carriage return or linefeed characters to an `INT` type will also fail.

If you want failed casts to return `NULL` instead of producing an error, you can use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) instead:

```
select try_convert(numeric, ' ')
```

If you want both to behave in the same way (whether that would mean both returning `NULL` or both returning `0` or `0.0` respectively) you need to somehow work your way around it.

To have the cast to `INT` return `NULL`, you could e.g. combine [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) with [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select try_convert(bigint, nullif('   ', ''))
```

This will also produce `NULL` for strings containing only (any number of) spaces.

If on the other hand, you prefer to see `0.0` results for empty strings or strings containing only spaces when casting to `NUMERIC`, you can filter these out explicitly:

```
select case when val like ' ' or val = '' then 0.0
       else  try_convert(numeric(5,1), val)
       end as val
  from strings
```

[This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=160f34763906cf346b113fcf4a1ab08d) shows what results the different queries yield for various whitespace and non-whitespace string input.