# Read each string that follows a char in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So let us say you have a string:

```
set @string = 'aaa,2,dqw,3,asdad,5,4'
```

I would like to read the chars that are after a char and a ","
So the result to this string would be:

```
 Result
--------
  2
  3
  5
```

How could I do this?is there a way to use `CHARINDEX` for this?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string).

Comment: This is helpfull but there is a catch,as you can see in my example I don't want to extract all numbers  for example after `asdad` I want to extract only the value `5` not the `4` also

Comment: Ideally, don't reach this situation in the first place. Distinct data ought to be stored in distinct places, not all shoved together into a string that you then have to untangle. Can this not be fixed upstream to avoid becoming this string in the first place?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, but one cannot always guarantee this. It might have come from a CSV file, in which case it may be junk data to you, but perhaps it was not to the designer.

Comment: @clifton_h - if it's coming from a CSV file, then you make sure you break it apart into separate columns during the process of importing the data into SQL, rather than letting it linger in a single text column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know, what you say is true. Always solve the underlying problem first. But sometimes life gives you lemons...or input boxes for customers to write stuff in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string is just like your example, using Charindex(',', `<string>`) works too.
Otherwise, use PATINDEX. It functions similarly,but you can also set it to recognize all numeric characters.

```
IF PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @String') <> 0
    THEN BEGIN
             SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @string), LEN(@string) )
             SET @var = SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string) )
             END
```

you now can do as you please with those variables.

To your exception, just use one more case statement and rid of it. No reason the code has to be too complicated.

Comment: Note to self: a phone is not the place for this. XD

Answer (score 0):

One more Approach using numbers table and [split string functions](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string = 'aaa,2,dqw,3,asdad,5,4'

;with cte
as
(
select * from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@string,',')
)
select 
* from cte where isnumeric(item)=1
```

**Output:**
2
3
5
4

if you are sure about no special characters in your data..You can use above,,but some times using  NUMERIC tends to show some characters as numbers

```
SELECT 
 ISNUMERIC('123') as '123'  --1
 ,ISNUMERIC('.') as '.' --Period ---1
 ,ISNUMERIC(',') as ',' --Comma ---1
```

In this case,you can use TRY_Parse available from SQL server 2012..

```
declare @string varchar(max)
    set @string = 'aaa,2,dqw,3,asdad,5,4'

    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select b.* from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@string,',') a
    cross apply
    (select try_parse(a.item as int) ) b(val)
    )
    select 
    * from cte where val is not null
```

Comment: The above piece of code gives 4 in the result which should not be displayed.

Comment: @tharunbandarupalli:4 is omitted by users as mistake,if thats the reason for your downvote.even accepeted answer gives 4

Comment: @ TheGameiswar . Sorry I was thinking to pick the numbers that follow an alphabet and then  ',' .