# How to convert a Excel format number to numeric(decimal or float)?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, decimal

I have a nvarchar(255) column which store numbers imported from excel long time ago.

Format like below:

```
7,242
(4,011)
-
(24,120.2)
-
4,234,091
```

"-" means 0 here.

I'm currently using "replace" to make it converted to decimal

```
convert(decimal(18,4),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace([Column a],'-',0),',',''),'(','-'),')',''))))
```

Anyhow, I think it is a little bit stupid. Any better way?

Comment: give a clear sample and a clear sample result too

Comment: Are we speaking about mssql (T-SQL)? convert(money,'1,234,567.8',1)  converts formatted string nice; convert(money,'-',1)  converts to 0 you can convert the result to any numeric type

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modified version of the function from [Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string) to handle your Excel values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
    (
     @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS 
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @intAlpha INT
       SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
       BEGIN
          WHILE @intAlpha > 0 
             BEGIN
                SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha,
                                        1, '')
                SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
             END
       END       
       RETURN CASE WHEN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)='-' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),@strAlphaNumeric) END 
    END
GO
```

You can then convert your values as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('7,242')
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('(4,011)')
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('-')
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('(24,120.2)')
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('-')
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('4,234,091')
```

The implementation is not necessarily better, but it makes it far easier to understand what the code is trying to achieve.