# String manipulation with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have the following table with (man-made) IDs.

```
ID       Name
AB12345  John
12346    Charles
...
```

How do I write a SELECT that returns only the number segment of the ID column? Like this:

```
ID       Name
12345    John
12346    Charles
...
```

Comment: make a scalar function the loops through each character and concatenates character to string value only if it is BETWEEN '0' AND '9'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    string) + 1) AS Number
FROM table
```

here string is equal to id

Answer (score 1):

You could write a regex to extract the numeric values that you are looking for.

This might help

[Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)