# Remove 'ID' from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which adds or removes zeros from ID.

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(STUFF(SystemID +
               REPLICATE('0', 9), 7, 0, REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(SystemID))), 9) as OBJECT 
FROM
    Products
```

So results will be something like this:

```
ID1230034
```

How can I remove 'ID' using this query? So it should be:

```
1230034
```

Thanks for all help:)

Comment: SUBSTRING that part away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to replace the first 2 chars of the string to an empty string:

```
SELECT STUFF(LEFT(STUFF(SystemID +
REPLICATE('0',9),7,0,REPLICATE('0',9-LEN(SystemID))),9), 1, 2, '') as OBJECT 
FROM Products
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replace function .

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(STUFF(SystemID +
REPLICATE('0',9),7,0,REPLICATE('0',9-LEN(SystemID))),9),'ID','') as OBJECT from Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function Right() -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx

assuming your ID's are always the same number of digits, do Right(ID,7)

Alternative Solution:

Use the Substring function -> http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

This can be helpful if the number of digits change :)

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution that can cope with prefix/suffix non-numeric characters can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16667251/2780791):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(
     @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(SystemID) 
from from Products
```