# Remove some characters from string sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string in my query like this,

```
X-AL33DX
```

I want to get 33 only from Query .

I'll try to use REPLACE but can't

```
REPLACE(REPLACE('X-AL33DX', '-', 'x'), ',', '')
```

Comment: what is your RDBMS? Also you have to explain a litle more what format your string will be like `33XX22` is possible?

Comment: SQL Server ....

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes those 33 can come anywhere in the string after X-

Comment: If the duplicate answers don't work for you, or your problem is somehow markedly different, then drop a comment and I can remove the dupe.  From what I can see, you want to remove letters (and hyphen), leaving you with the number `33.`.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string