# Extract number from a GUID

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any possiblity to extract only the numbers from a GUID? I'm trying to achieve this because I don't want to display the GUID in a form, but the numbers within, which also are unique.

Comment: post a sample guid and the output

Comment: Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") will give you some idea

Comment: @Sajeetharan 

This is the GUID - D364800B-D75E-456A-90F7-12A2751350BF
And I would like to extract - 36480075456907122571350

Comment: @cdrrrr, This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). what is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?The numbers within are not guaranteed to make a unique number.

Comment: @Nkosi - it appears to be what? I might not understand all the answers, my english is not excellent.

Comment: Note that the number you extract this way is not globally unique like guid itself is. Also some guids do not contain those "numbers" at all.

Comment: @cdrrrr check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string GetNumbersFromGuid(Guid Item)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    var guidArray = Item.ToString().ToCharArray();

    int n;
    foreach (var item in guidArray)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out n) == true)
        {
            result += item.ToString();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var MyValue = GetNumbersFromGuid(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use IsDigit to get only the numbers

```
   var guidstring = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
   var getNumbers = (from t in guidstring
                              where char.IsDigit(t)
                              select t).ToArray();
```

**[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lOY4XC)**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But, how to achieve it into SQL Server? Do you have something on your mind? Make abstraction of c#.

Comment: @cdrrrr check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string