# How to remove unique characters from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

What function can I use to get rid of certain characters within a string? I know I can use the `REPLACE()` function but there are around 30 variables which will need doing so hoping for a more efficient route.

**Example:**

What it currently shows:

```
BasicPay_5000
CarAllowance_6000
Bonus_7000
```

What I need it to show:

```
5000
6000
7000
```

Is there a function that removes all characters up to the pre-defined character? E.g. by writing a statement which removes all characters up to `_` (underscore).

Comment: Please, check out the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string article. This may be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
select substr('BasicPay_5000', instr('BasicPay_5000','_') + 1) from dual
```

BasicPay_5000 can be replaced with any data you have, if its in the said format

Answer (score 1):

This uses a regular expression to get the numbers at the end of the string.

`[0-9]`  -  any digit

`{1,}` -  1 or more of the previous search term

`$` - anchor the search to the end of the line.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Basic_Pay_5000','[0-9]{1,}$') FROM dual
```