# How to extract number from a string

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-control

I've a string like 'intercompany creditors {DEMO[[1]]}'. I want to extract only the numbers from the string, in example just '1'.

How to do this in Invantive SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to get only numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: @andrii this is not SQL Server.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, sorry, my bad.

Comment: To be sure: do you need the number '1' as a string or as an integer / decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do so with `substr` (get some piece of text from specific positions in the text) and `instr` (get the position from a specific piece of text inside some other text):

```
select substr
       ( d
       , instr(d, '[[') + 2
       , instr(d, ']]') - instr(d, '[[') - 2
       )
from   ( select 'intercompany creditors {DEMO[[1]]}' d 
         from dual@DataDictionary
       ) x
```