# extract number from a string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Data:

```
AT_SendMail_v1

AT_Certificate_v10

AT_Certificate_v100
```

And I want this output:

```
AT_SendMail_v2

AT_Certificate_v11

AT_Certificate_v101
```

I have this code but it doesn't work for the numbers that they more than 19:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT([internalname],1)) = 1 
        THEN LEFT([internalname],LEN([internalname])-1)  + cast((CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([internalname],1)) + 1) as varchar(100)) 
        ELSE [internalname] + '_v1'
        END
       ,[id]
FROM [task]
```

thanks :)

Comment: Try picking up everything after _v till you reach space and then check it if it is numeric or not and increment it if it is

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: Everytime ends with `_v.....`?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me... what am I missing? Your 3 test cases result in your 3 expected results.

Comment: but how can i picking up everything after _v?

Comment: in my code if I have  _v19, it writes _v110 instead of _v20

Comment: @kauthar check an answer, looks like It workes as you need.

Comment: Any answer to this is just prolonging the agony you are going to deal with. The real issue here is that you have violated 1NF by sticking two values into the same tuple. You should split version to its own column and this issue suddenly just disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number is always the end of the string:

using `patindex()`:

```
select 
    name
  , new_name = case when patindex('%[_]v[1234567890]%',name) > 0
      then left(name,(patindex('%[_]v[1234567890]%',name)+1))
         + convert(varchar(10),convert(int
           ,right(name,len(name)-(patindex('%[_]v[1234567890]%',name)+1)))
           +1)
       else name+'_v1'
    end
from task
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AWPXB86451

returns:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
|         name         |       new_name       |
+----------------------+----------------------+
| AT_SendMail_v1       | AT_SendMail_v2       |
| AT_Certificate_v10   | AT_Certificate_v11   |
| AT_Certificate_v_v50 | AT_Certificate_v_v51 |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBSTRING` to get number after `_v`, after it check If It is numeric using `ISNUMERIC`, after It increase that number by 1, convert It to string and concat string.

```
DECLARE @internalname NVARCHAR(40)
SET @internalname = 'AT_SendMail_v19'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@internalname, CHARINDEX('_v', @internalname) + 2, LEN(@internalname))) = 1
         THEN SUBSTRING(@internalname,+2, CHARINDEX('_v',@internalname)) + CAST(SUBSTRING(@internalname, CHARINDEX('_v', @internalname) + 2, LEN(@internalname)) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(60))
         ELSE @internalname + '_v1'
    END
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC can have shortcomings, as it will recognize dollar signs and scientific notation as numbers as well. Try `SELECT ISNUMERIC($)` or `SELECT ISNUMERIC(1e4)` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to increment the numbers, you can then build it into your string...

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(20) = 'AT_SendMail_v1';

DECLARE @intCharIndex INT = CHARINDEX('_v',@str);

IF(@intCharIndex = 0)

BEGIN 

    SELECT 'No string found';
END

IF(@intCharIndex > 0)

BEGIN 
    DECLARE @int INT = LEN(@str) - @intCharIndex - 1;

    DECLARE @intVersion INT = RIGHT(@str,@int) + 1;

    SELECT LEFT(@str,@intCharIndex) + 'v' + RTRIM(CAST(@intVersion AS NVARCHAR(4)));
END
```

Comment: It returns only number, also what if string will be provided like: `'AT_SendMail_'?

Comment: I state it only returns the number in the code, the point being this can be used to extract the number and increment, this can then be plugged back into the string. Based on the question, there is nothing to suggest that would ever be the case. But, I take your point and have amended it to check if there is an index of what is being looked for so it would not error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
declare @test varchar(50) = 'AT_SendMail_v1';

select Output = case when ISNUMERIC( substring ( @test , charindex('_v',@test)+2 , len(@test)) )=1 then

         left (@test , charindex('_v',@test)+1) + cast( cast(substring ( @test , charindex('_v',@test)+2 , len(@test)) as int)+1 as varchar )
         else
         @test+'_v1' end;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TVC50298).

Comment: It will fail if value will be like `'AT_SendMail'`

Comment: ISNUMERIC can have shortcomings, as it will recognize dollar signs and scientific notation as numbers as well. Try SELECT ISNUMERIC($) or SELECT ISNUMERIC(1e4) and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

that was the best code for me, thanks :)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('_v', [internalname], 1) <> 0 THEN LEFT([internalname], CHARINDEX('_v', [internalname], 1) + 1) + CAST(CAST(RIGHT([internalname], LEN([internalname]) - CHARINDEX('_v', [internalname], 1) - 1) AS INT) + 1 AS VARCHAR(100)) 
        ELSE [internalname] + '_v1' 
    END 
    ,[id] 
FROM [task]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this that caters for ANY number after the _v

```
Select Left(internalName, Len(internalName) - CharIndex('v_', Reverse(internalName)) + 1) + Cast((Cast((Right(internalName, CharIndex('v_', Reverse(internalName)) -1)) As Integer) + 1) As NVarchar(32))
From task
```