# extract phone number from string format either (xxx)xxxxxxx or (xxx)xxx-xxxx

Tags: sql, regex

I have phone number field in either of these two formats
 (xxx)xxxxxxx or (xxx)xxx-xxxx

I want to extract and format the number as xxxxxxxxxx, number only. Is there a simple way in sql select statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
column_sample,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone , '(', '') , ')', '') , '-', '') as phone
FROM tbl_sample;
```

Comment: Thank you, However, there is still space in the place of '(' and ')'. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Can you please give an example? @JackieGMa

Comment: copied from results 206 7891381, should be 2067891381, original format  (206)789-1381

Comment: There should be no space. But you can add one more replace which replaces space.

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone , '(', '') , ')', '') , '-', ''), ' ', '') as phone

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to answer coding questions without an example of the code with which you are working. That being said, something like this might be what you are look for:

```
SELECT
[Phone Numbers]
,FORMAT([Phone Numbers],'(##########') AS [Formatted Phone]
FROM tbl_sample
```