# SQL Sort Numeric Strings After Split

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have char values in a table column which are in the format "IS-" and then 1 to 5 numbers, a possible period with either 2 numbers or a letter following the period.

> Examples are, IS-1, IS-12, IS-123, IS-123.11, IS-123.a.

I need to split the string so that I grab only the number part, sort the strings ASC, and the bring the strings back together the way they were.

Explanation. I have the following set of values, `IS-1170, IS-1171, IS-1172, IS-1173, IS-1174, IS-870.a, IS-871.a, IS-872.a.` As you can see, because IS-1 comes before IS-8 they are sorting out of numerical order.

Any idea where to begin? I was thinking of using CASE, but I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to exclude any values, or just have it laid out different?

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string question. Function approach may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do string functions in your `ORDER BY` to remove only the number.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT col
FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(col,4,20)) = 1
              THEN SUBSTRING(col,4,20)
              ELSE LEFT(SUBSTRING(col,4,20),CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(col,4,20),0)-1)
         END AS NUMERIC)
```

This will first remove the `IS-` and check if the rest of the string is a number.  If it is, it will leave the decimal digits, otherwise it will remove the `.` and the following alpha characters.

This is assuming your intended ordering in the case of numeric decimal places would be:

```
IS-123.A
IS-123.1
IS-123.2
```

If you don't care about what's after the decimal/period, then simply:

```
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(col,4,20),CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(col,4,20),0)-1) AS NUMERIC)
```

Comment: Das ist fantastisch:)

Comment: WOW! Thanks Aaron. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this might help you:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourExample VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('IS-1, IS-12, IS-123, IS-123.11, IS-123.a.')
,('IS-1170, IS-1171, IS-1172, IS-1173, IS-1174, IS-870.a, IS-871.a, IS-872.a');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(m.YourExample,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SplitAtComma
    FROM @mockup AS m
)
,NumberExtracted AS
(
    SELECT s.ID
          ,part.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS OnePart
          ,CAST('<y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(part.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'.','-'),'-','</y><y>') + '</y>' AS XML).value('/y[2]/text()[1]','int') AS TheNumber 
    FROM Splitted AS s
    CROSS APPLY s.SplitAtComma.nodes('/x') AS A(part)
)
SELECT *
FROM NumberExtracted
ORDER BY ID,TheNumber;
```

The first CTE uses a string-split via XML to get all values within the original string (btw: **never store comma separated values!**).
The second CTE will use the same approach to extract the number, typesafe as INT.
You can use this in an `ORDER BY` finally.

The result:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| ID | OnePart   | TheNumber |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | IS-1      | 1         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | IS-12     | 12        |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | IS-123    | 123       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | IS-123.11 | 123       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | IS-123.a. | 123       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-870.a  | 870       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-871.a  | 871       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-872.a  | 872       |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-1170   | 1170      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-1171   | 1171      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-1172   | 1172      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-1173   | 1173      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | IS-1174   | 1174      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hint: You'll have to use `LTRIM` and/or `RTRIM` to avoid leading or trailing blanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##table1', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE ##table1;  
create table ##table1(col1 varchar(20))

declare @query as nvarchar(max)
declare @var1 as varchar(max)='IS-1, IS-12, IS-123, IS-123.11, IS-123.a.,IS-1170, IS-1171, IS-1172, IS-1173, IS-1174, IS-870.a, IS-871.a, IS-872.a.'
set @var1=replace(@var1,',','''),(''')
set @var1='('''+@var1+''')'
set @var1=replace(@var1,' ','')
set @query='insert into ##table1 values'+@var1
EXEC sp_executesql @query
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##table2', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE ##table2;  
select * into ##table2  from ##table1 order by cast(replace(replace(replace(col1,'IS-',''),'.a.',''),'.a','') as float)

declare @results varchar(max)
select @results = coalesce(@results + ', ', '') +  convert(varchar(12),col1) from ##table2
select @results

DROP TABLE ##table1 
DROP TABLE ##table2
```