# How to write a SQL Server query to get the required result from the below string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve the value inside a Text. Here is my example:

```
<Host_In_Params>{"Zip_Code":"94941"}</Host_In_Params>
```

How can I easily get the result `94941` from the above string value?

Comment: First you need to show us what you have tried and where you got stuck. This isnt'a `code-for-free` service. Please read [how to ask a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: Maybe solution on this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json function

```
SELECT 
     '{"Zip_Code":"94941"}'
    ,JSON_VALUE('{"Zip_Code":"94941"}', '$.Zip_Code') AS YourValue
```

[image]

Here is a second idea: (Quick and Dirty)

[image]

```
DECLARE @test varchar(100);  
SELECT @test = '<Host_In_Params>{"Zip_Code":"94941"}</Host_In_Params>';  
SELECT SUBSTRING(
             @test
            ,CHARINDEX('Zip_Code', @test) + 11
            ,5
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.But I am using Sql Server 2012 and it is throwing error while I executing it : "JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: I changed my post. CHARINDEX is compatible since 2008. My code, is only valid if your value is on 5 Char. (But you have the basis to change it if needed)

Comment: Super then :). Do not hesitate to mark my answer as validated then

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question the answer is

```sql
DECLARE @CODE VARCHAR(50)
SET @CODE = '{"Zip_Code":"94941"}'
SELECT @CODE

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING (REVERSE(@CODE), CHARINDEX('"', @CODE) +1 , 5))
```

This completely varies based on the data in the `@code`.