# SQL - remove/replace numbers from a string for all column

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a column with the numbers that are part of a string for the entire column.

For example the column containing the empid like

1. A12SD9
2. A12SA1
3. A10AA1

I have seen examples for a single string but I would like to apply it to the full column.

Comment: Make it more brief, your question is not clear

Comment: Hi Pratik  thak you for your prompt replay. What I am trying to do is to extract the numbers from a column so in the example I gave it would be for the first row 129 for the second 121 and 101 to the third . Thank you

Comment: @Joaquim is the format of value will remain same i.e. only 2nd,3rd and 6th character would be number always? anyway this will help you in either case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string & http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b383/36

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...