# Sort by first matching number then by second matching number and so on in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

sort by first matching number then by second matching number in SQL

Suppose, I have a table entries as following.

```
Btc0504
Btc_0007_Shd_01
Btc_007_Shd_01
Bcd0007_Shd_7
ptc00044
Brg0007_Shd_6
Btc0075_Shd
Bcc43
MR_Tst_etc0565
wtc0004_Shd_4
vtc_Btc0605
```

so it should bring records as following.

```
wtc0004_Shd_4
Bcc43
ptc00044
Btc_007_Shd_01
Btc_0007_Shd_01
Brg0007_Shd_6
Bcd0007_Shd_7
Btc0075_Shd
Btc0504
MR_Tst_etc0565
Btc_vtc0605
```

So basically it sorts by numbers only, words are only separator of numbers.

Here middle strings can be of any numbers.

They are not fixed and this pattern is also not fixed.

so there can be more strings and numbers with row. i.e. a1b2c3d4e5..., u7g2u9w2s8...

So require dynamic solution.

Example table is given below.

http://rextester.com/IDQ22263

Comment: use this UDF and sort by this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667431/440030

Comment: Probably you could write some CLR function to do this with regular expressions.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni. I tried it. It gives me Btc0075_Shd after Bcd0007_Shd_7. because it removes all alphabets. so it brings 77 before 75. where as my comparison requires 7 and 7 differently.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. Ya I also thought that way. But I need to paginate records based on this (like bring only top 10 records of this sort). so in CLR i will have to bring all records to do this.

Comment: No, you don't. With a CLR UDF you could do the filtering in place. It works like using any built-in function. It also supports context connection.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. Oh my bad (I started thinking about .Net CLR, Wasnt so good at abbreviations.). Ya. will try that way if not any other way. :)

Comment: Yes it IS .Net CLR and it is supported by SQL server. I use it for things where I find it hard or slow to do with MS SQL T-SQL itself. For example, I created a C# function that parses a comma separated list of IDs to a table and then returns matching rows (an IN query). I had the same thing in T-SQL but it was timing out if the IDs were over 10-15K. With CLR UDF, even 20-30K IDs returned data sub second.

Comment: Without using fixed markers such as `Btc`, I don't think it's possible to write a general query in SQL Server.  SQL Server does not have any built in regex support, and regex is really what you would need for the general solution you have in mind.

Comment: Note: You might try with translate() and string_split() for a solution in T-SQL but I still think it would be best with CLR.

Comment: Am I the only one who understood your question correctly :) Or am the one who didn't understand at all ? Would you please edit your question how would 'Btc_007_Shd_01' or 'Mr0007ec01' sort.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. I think yes. U r the only one (or at least first one). In ur case it will be great if 007 can come first instead of 0007. :) Updated Question.

Comment: @CetinBasoz  But we can ignore that zeros as it is not on my priority if any comes first. :)

Comment: Yes that is what I understood too, Btc0007_Shd_01 would be treated as 7 and 1. (I think I will write a CLR UDF at the end:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you would have 2 number blocks at most and each number would be 10 digits at most, I created a sample CLR UDF like this for you (DbProject - SQL CLR Database project):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString CustomStringParser(SqlString str)
    {
        int depth = 2; // 2 numbers at most
        int width = 10; // 10 digits at most

        List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        var matches = Regex.Matches((string)str, @"\d+");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            numbers.Add(int.Parse(match.Value).ToString().PadLeft(width, '0'));
        }
        return string.Join("", numbers.ToArray()).PadRight(depth*width);
    }
}
```

I added this to the 'test' database as follows:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ufn_MyCustomParser]') AND
                    type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' ) )
  DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_MyCustomParser]
GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.[assemblies] AS [a]
            WHERE   [a].[name] = 'DbProject' AND
                    [a].[is_user_defined] = 1 )
  DROP ASSEMBLY DbProject;
GO


CREATE ASSEMBLY DbProject
FROM 'C:\SQLCLR\DbProject\DbProject\bin\Debug\DbProject.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_MyCustomParser ( @csv NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS EXTERNAL NAME
  DbProject.[UserDefinedFunctions].CustomStringParser;
GO
```

Note: SQL server 2012 (2017 has strict security problem that you need to handle).

Finally tested with this T-SQL:

```
declare @MyTable table (col1 varchar(50));
insert into @MyTable values
('Btc0504'),
('Btc0007_Shd_7'),
('Btc0007_Shd_01'),
('Btc0007_Shd_6'),
('MR_Tst_Btc0565'),
('Btc0004_Shd_4'),
('Btc_BwwwQAZtc0605'),
('Btc_Bwwwwe12541edddddtc0605'),
('QARTa1b2');
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
ORDER BY dbo.ufn_MyCustomParser(col1);
```

Output:

```
col1
QARTa1b2
Btc0004_Shd_4
Btc0007_Shd_01
Btc0007_Shd_6
Btc0007_Shd_7
Btc0504
MR_Tst_Btc0565
Btc_BwwwQAZtc0605
Btc_Bwwwwe12541edddddtc0605
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query does the following: it uses `patindex` function, to extract index in a string of a pattern:

1. firstly, it extracts beginning of number, searching for a digit.
2. Secondly, it extracts end of a number searching for digit followed by non-digit.

Having done that, we have everything to extract a nuber from a string and sort by it after converting (casting) it to an integer.

Try this query:

```
declare @tbl table (col1 varchar(50));
insert into @tbl values
('Btc0504'),
('Btc0007_Shd_7'),
('Btc0007_Shd_6'),
('MR_Tst_Btc0565'),
('Btc0004_Shd_4'),
('Btc_Btc0605');

select col1 from (
    select col1,
           PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col1) [startIndex],
           case PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', col1) when 0 then LEN(col1) else     PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', col1) end [endIndex]
    from @tbl
) [a]
order by CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1) as int)
```

I came up with another solution, which is very compact and more general:

```
;with cte as (
    select 1 [n], col1, STUFF(col1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', col1), 1, '.') refined_col1 from @tbl
    union all
    select n+1, col1, STUFF(refined_col1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', refined_col1), 1, '.') from cte
    where n < 100 -- <--this number must be greater than the greatest amount of non-digits in a col1, this way, you are sure that you'll remove all unnecesary characters
)

select col1, refined_col1 from cte
where PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', refined_col1) = 0
order by CAST(replace(refined_col1, '.', '') as int)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: The OP is asking for `dynamic` solution.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I think it will work with any input... Removed dependancy on `Btc` substring.

Comment: In case there are 2 number blocks, he wants to sort with first one and then second one.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks for remark, added another solution.

Comment: You are getting closer but I am afraid that wouldn't work too (try 'Btc0007_Shd_01').

Comment: @CetinBasoz Well, it will! The recursive CTE will convert that to `...0007.....01` and the select query will treat is as number 701, which will be sorted naturally :) I intentionally left dots after recursive CTE, so OP can decide, now he can get something like 1.3.7 easily and there is a built-in datatype in SQL that can sort this kind of data.

Comment: @CetinBasoz And please, try the query before supposing it won't work.

Comment: You are not getting it. I just tried and I was right. 'Btc0007_Shd_01' was the last row when it should be first for the sample values ( 1 < 4 ).

Answer (score 0):

I will begin my answer by saying that the best long term solution for you is to fix your data model.  If you have need to use the various portions of the entry in queries, for sorting, etc., then consider storing them in separate bona-fide columns.

That being said, one workaround is to use basic string operations to extract the two components you want so use for sorting.  Note carefully that we have to cast them to numbers, because otherwise they won't sort properly as text.

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING(entry, PATINDEX('%Btc[0-9]%', entry) + 3, 4) AS INT),
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Shd_', entry) > 0
         THEN
         CAST(SUBSTRING(entry,
                        CHARINDEX('Shd_', entry) + 4,
                        LEN(entry) - CHARINDEX('Shd_', entry) -4) AS INT)
         ELSE 1 END;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: btc_, shd_ and those strings are not fixed. I updated question for more details.

Comment: @HardikViradiya Please post your exact question to avoid being downvoted.

Comment: It was exact question. But still people are not answering what I want, instead they tried giving fixed values of "btc_", which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

> At the beginning I does not recommend the next approach for
>   performance aspect , you should fix the root cause of your data.

For handling dynamic inputs, I Think you should create UDF function for extracting the numbers only like next:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_ExtratcNumbersOnly
(@string VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string) <> 0
    SET @string = STUFF(@string,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string),1,'')
    RETURN cast (@string as int)
END
GO
```

Then use it as next:-

```
declare @MyTable table (col1 varchar(50));
insert into @MyTable values
('Btc0504'),
('Btc0007_Shd_7'),
('Btc0007_Shd_6'),
('MR_Tst_Btc0565'),
('Btc0004_Shd_4'),
('Btc_BwwwQAZtc0605'),
('Btc_Bwwwwe12541edddddtc0605'),
('QARTa1b2c3d4e5');

select * from @MyTable 
order by (dbo.udf_ExtratcNumbersOnly(col1))
```

Result:-

```
Btc0004_Shd_4
Btc0007_Shd_6
Btc0007_Shd_7
Btc0504
MR_Tst_Btc0565
Btc_BwwwQAZtc0605
QARTa1b2c3d4e5
Btc_Bwwwwe12541edddddtc0605
```

**[Demo.](http://rextester.com/CIUWLJ58391)**

Comment: root cause of data is our organisation i am working in. :(

Comment: Sorry that I had to update my example to see what was issue with your approach. Please check with my updated example and you will find issue in result.

Comment: I can not get the issue that you mentioned, what is the issue exactly ?

Comment: Ur query has some syntax errors. Not being run. can we have any SQL fiddle? so that I can show issue. As I have figured out logic given by you.

Comment: Please check this. It has similar function as urs. http://rextester.com/OITZJ61236

Comment: in that Btc43 is coming last. which should come after Bcd0007_Shd_7

Comment: Try 'Btc0007_Shd_01'.

Comment: `Btc0007_Shd_01` it gonna converts to `701`, what is the issue of it ?, did i missed  anything ?

Comment: Yes you missed that 1 is less than 4, 6 and 7. It should be converted to 7 and 1 as values (2 numeric columns represented in one string). OP's design seems to be bad but it is what he has.

Comment: You mean `Btc0007_Shd_01` should be converted to `71` ?

Comment: No :) It should be converted to 7 and 1 (2 number blocks, they are first converted to numbers and then sorted first on first block and then second)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tally table/numbers table to get each character and find only numbers and then combine the numbers in order to form a string(which can be casted into bigint). Then you can order based on this string.

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/BUOBO8982)**</kbd>

```
; with numbers as (
    select top 10000
        r= row_number() over( order by (select null))
    from sys.objects o1 
        cross join sys.objects o2
   )

, onlynumbers as
(
    select * from t 
    cross apply
    ( select part =substring(num,r,1),r
      from numbers where r<=len(num)
     )y
    where part  like '[0-9]' 
)

, finalorder as
(
    select num,cast(replace(stuff
    ((
        select ','+part
        from onlynumbers o2 
        where o2.num=o1.num
        order by o2.r
        for xml path('')
        ),1,1,''),',','') as bigint) b
  from onlynumbers o1
  group by num
   )
 select num from finalorder order by b asc
```

Comment: Like other answers, this too is ignoring the fact that OPs pattern might have 2 blocks of numbers and in that case the sorting should be done first by first block and then the second. For example, in your sample try including 'Btc0007_Shd_01' which should be returned as the 1st row. As I said, it is best not to try to solve this by T-SQL but CLR.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I think you would need regex for a reliable arbitrary solution.  Since the OP is using SQL Server, this is not possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,  "impossible" ???? A strong word even for SQL server. As I already said a few times, SQL server supports CLR and you could do Regex matching (not a must in this case) with CLR.