# Leading zeros after getting numeric part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012.
Need to get numeric part with 6 figures, if not enough figures fill with leading zeros.
Code is nvarchar type.

TABLE_A Before update

```
Id  Code
1  s33404tft 
2  dd345ui
3  456567t
4  8746
```

TABLE_A After Update

```
Id  Code
1  033404
2  000345
3  456567
4  008746
```

sql script:

```
 Update table_A
    SET Code=FORMAT((SELECT SUBSTRING(code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', code + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code) + 1) AS Number 
              FROM Table_A),'000000')
```

It does not work.

Comment: Regex is probably the best, or at least very suitable, tool for doing this, but SQL Server does not have much regex support.  I might try to handle this outside of SQL Server.

Comment: @graphene Hi, look at [T H I S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: The provided link only gives the numeric part, which I already have in the select part. I need also the leading zeroes.

Comment: @graphene you didn't explain what you want, or what the problem is. For one thing, FORMAT doesn't work with strings. You'd have to `CAST` that string to `int` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is concatenating leading zeros and using `RIGHT` to extract the desired value:

```
UPDATE table_A
SET Code =
    RIGHT('000000' + SUBSTRING(code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', code + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code) + 1), 6)
    FROM Table_A;
```

Comment: there is one problem: it will ignore code with 8746 for example. I added one more example above.

Comment: @graphene, I ran the code on my machine and I get `008746` instead of `NULL`. Let me see if I can figure out why you are getting `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replicate function for [padding leading zeros in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx)

Please check the referred document for the USD function udfLeftSQLPadding
Then you can use it in following format:

```
select dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding('12345',6,'0')
```

Additionally, to fetch only the numeric values may be you can use ClearNonNumericCharacters UDF where I shared at [Remove Non-Numeric Character](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/remove-non-numeric-characters-in-sql-string-expression.aspx)

So your script will be as follows

```
Update table_A
set 
Code = dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding( dbo.ClearNonNumericCharacters(Code), 6, '0')
```

Comment: When I use UPDATE table_A
SET Code=(select dbo.fnUdfLeftSQLPadding(Code,6,'0') FROM Table_A) gives an error (yes I have created the function first). I cannot use TOP 1 as it would update all rows with 033404.

Comment: @graphene that's a problem with the query itself. There's no reason to use a SELECT inside FORMAT

Comment: I added a second query and a second function named udfLeftSQLPadding that removes non-numeric values and gets only the numeric data

Answer (score 1):

`FORMAT` doesn't work with text types. The extracted numeric part would have to be converted to an integer first in order to format it, eg :

```
update Table_A
set code=FORMAT(cast( SUBSTRING(code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', code + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code) + 1) 
                      as int)
                ,'00000000')
```

For example :

```
declare @table_A table (ID int, Code nvarchar(20))
insert into @table_A (ID,Code)
values
(1,'s33404tft'),
(2,'dd345ui'),
(3,'456567t'),
(4,'8746');

update @table_A
set code=FORMAT(cast(SUBSTRING(code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', code + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code) + 1) as int)
                ,'00000000')


select * from @table_A
```

Produces :

```
ID  Code
1   00033404
2   00000345
3   00456567
4   00008746
```

Comment: @graphene it returns `00008746`, not null. I copy/pasted the actual results. Have you tried running *this* script? Perhaps your table contains something that looks like 8746 but has other leading/trailing characters?

Comment: yes. It is working. Thanks. Yours and Dan Guzman scripts are working.