# Formatting Phone Number to US Format (###) ###-####

Tags: sql, sql-server, format, substring, phone-number

I am trying to reformat around 1000 phone numbers in a SQL Server database to US format `(###) ###-####`

Currently the phone numbers are formatted in all sorts of ways ranging from ##########, ###-###-####, one is ###)-###-####. There is also one with only six digits.

As a first step I've been attempting to isolate the numbers in all of these rows but its just returning the same as they were already.

`select SUBSTRING(phone, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', phone), LEN(phone)) from people`

How could I best go about writing a query which would format them all as `(###) ###-####`?

expected output:

```
(555) 222-3333
(555) 444-3030
(555) 092-0920
(555) 444-4444
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output would help considerably. [mcve]

Comment: 1. [Filter out numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16667251/11683) and cast to int. 2. [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the int as `(###)####-####`.

Comment: Great that you have the output...what about the input? And what about the phone numbers with only 7 numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since one suggestion was made already and the suggestion there to isolate numbers in a string uses a while loop I need to post an alternative to that which doesn't use any looping. Instead it utilizes a tally or numbers table. There are lots of solutions for those. I like to use a view which is lightning fast and has zero reads.

Here is my version of a tally table.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Next we need a table valued function to remove the characters that are not numbers using our tally table. This is also super fast because we are using our tally table instead of looping.

```
create function GetOnlyNumbers
(
    @SearchVal varchar(8000)
) returns table as return

    with MyValues as
    (
        select substring(@SearchVal, N, 1) as number
            , t.N
        from cteTally t 
        where N <= len(@SearchVal)
            and substring(@SearchVal, N, 1) like '[0-9]'
    )

    select distinct NumValue = STUFF((select number + ''
                from MyValues mv2
                order by mv2.N
                for xml path('')), 1, 0, '')
    from MyValues mv
```

Now that we have all the legwork done we can focus on the task at hand. Since you didn't provide any sample data I just made up some stuff. I am not really sure if this is representative of your data or not but this works on the sample data I created.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something(SomeVal varchar(100))

insert #Something values
('Maybe you have other stuff in here. 5552223333 additional characters can cause grief')
, ('321-654-9878')
, ('123)-333-4444')
, ('1234567')

select replace(format(try_convert(bigint, n.NumValue), '(###) ###-####'), '() ', '')
    , n.NumValue
from #Something s
cross apply dbo.GetOnlyNumbers(s.SomeVal) n
```

The output for the formatted data looks like this:

```
(555) 222-3333
(321) 654-9878
(123) 333-4444
123-4567
```

Answer (score 0):

If this reformatting something that is going to be used repeatedly then a creating a UDF as suggested by @GSerg would be the way to go.

If this is just a one time clean-up you could give this a try.

First replace all of the numbers with empty strings with a series of nested REPLACE() functions.

```
DECLARE @PhoneNumbers TABLE (

Number varchar (20))

INSERT INTO @PhoneNumbers VALUES ('(888-239/1239')
INSERT INTO @PhoneNumbers VALUES ('222.1234')

SELECT 
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(Number, '0', '')
                                , '1', '')
                            , '2', '')
                        , '3', '')
                    , '4', '')
                , '5', '')
            , '6', '')
        , '7', '')
    , '8', '')
, '9', '')
FROM @PhoneNumbers
```

Then take those result non-numeric characters and put them each in their own nested REPLACE() function and format the result. You will have to deal with each length individually. If you have only 7 digits and you want to format it to have 10 digits what do you want those extra 3 digits to be. This will handle the 10 digit phone numbers.

```
SELECT FORMAT(x.NumbersOnly, '(###) ###-####')
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(BIGINT,
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(Number, '(', '')
                , '-', '')
            , '/', '')
        , '.', '')
    ) AS NumbersOnly
    FROM @PhoneNumbers
) x
WHERE LEN(x.NumbersOnly) = 10
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e40b2b6cfb67e4bff9997310dbdf8aa5).