# How to format data in column for WHERE clause just before executing SELECT?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I am using Microsoft SQL Server with already stored data.
In one of my tables I can find data like:

```sh
+--------+------------+
| id     | value      |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | 12-34      |
| 2      | 5678       |
| 3      | 1-23-4     |
+--------+------------+
```

I realized that the **VALUE** column was not properly formatted when inserted.
What I am trying to achieve is to get id by given value:

```sql
SELECT d.id FROM data d WHERE d.value = '1234';
```

Is there any way to format data in column just before **SELECT** clause?
Should I create new view and modify column in that view or maybe use complicated **REGEX** to get only digits (with **LIKE** comparator)?

- P.S. I manage database in Jakarta EE project using Hibernate.
- P.S.2. I am not able to modify stored data.

Comment: If `value` should be storing what looks like an integer value, why is it a `varchar`? If the data type was correct, you'd never be able to have a value like `'12-34'`. i would suggest fixing the data and the design, and then you can't store bad values.

Comment: Sorry, financial and accountancy software usually works as somebody designed it about ten years ago, no posibbility to change this in this particular situation.

Comment: Financial and accounting application developers knew that numerical data should be stored in a numerical data type 10 years ago. I use one at the office that was designed in the 1970's and even *that* knows what a number is. And Accountants know far too well that `2` is less than `100` (but your application doesn't think that).

Comment: Do not know if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `replace()` before the comparison:

```
WHERE REPLACE(d.value, '-', '') = '1234'
```