# How to extract the float part from nvarchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field contains characters and numbers in different format
like

```
f v/45.23698,sdfsdf
25.369xzczxc xcvxv
erwer ewrwr 2.36
```

I want to extract the numbers part with decimal (any number of decimals) omitting any characters in any case and any symbols ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ = + / * \ | ? : "

```
45.23698
25.369
2.36
```

if there is any errors like

```
df df , 23.45.67 dfg fdg
```

I want to return 23.45 only (ignoring the others) or 23.4567 (ignoring the second decimal point) it doesn't matter at all .. the two solutions are acceptable

```
23.45
23.45678
```

both are acceptable

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution [Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string) with some modifications from me to achieve my goal as follows

```
create FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(
    @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS

BEGIN
  DECLARE @intAlpha INT
  SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
  BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '')
      SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    END
  END
  RETURN      ISNULL( SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric,1,CHARINDEX('.',@strAlphaNumeric,1)) ,0)     +REPLACE( ISNULL( SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric,CHARINDEX('.',@strAlphaNumeric,1)+1,LEN(@strAlphaNumeric)) ,0) , '.' , '')


END

GO

SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('621.382.003/? ?')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('f g / 23.2525 gg')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('2.3658 dfg')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('sdfgsg 5.258')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('23.45.67')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric(',621.382.003/? ?')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('.f g / 23.2525 gg')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('2.3658dfg')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('sdfgsg5.258')
SELECT  dbo.udf_GetNumeric('.23.45.67')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are separated by spaces (as in your sample data), then a simple method is:

```
select t.*, s.value
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.field, ' ') s
where try_convert(float, s.value) is not null;
```

This returns all numbers in the string.

If you want the first number in the string, you can use logic such as:

```
select t.*, v.str,
       left(v.str, patindex('%[^0-9.]%', v.str + ' ')) as val
```

This is not perfect -- for instance, it will return strings that have two decimal points -- but it definitely works on your data.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bf82de327c728f2a2daee2797ac36b6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Mariam . . . There is a second answer as well.