# Extract only numeric values from String column

Tags: sql

I have a column of values that are as shown below:

```
ID
x-644478134
x-439220334
x-645948923
x-10686843432
x-4273883234
```

**I would like to return a column like so:**

```
ID
644478134
439220334
645948923
10686843432
4273883234
```

Can someone advise how to do this cleanly? I believe it is something to do with substring but not sure exactly

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(d.ID)
FROM data d
```

Comment: Always starts with "x-" ??? If so, try: Select substring(ID,3,LEN(ID)-2)

Comment: Is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `substring`, `charindex` and `len` functions such as below, assuming the dash (-) is the separator of the text and numeric part:

```
declare @x varchar(50) = 'a-0123'
select substring(@x,CHARINDEX('-',@x,1)+1,len(@x)-CHARINDEX('-',@x,1))
```

If you are sure that ID always starts with x-, then:

```
Select substring(ID,3,LEN(ID)-2)
```