# Get numbers from the character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server which contains a characters and a random numbers or a dash and random character string. I want to extract the numbers to different field. Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
create table stage.test(
    geo_code varchar(50) null
)
    
insert into stage.test values ('mobile-pensacola (ft walt) (686)')
insert into stage.test values ('rj-globo rio (76008)' )
insert into stage.test values ('ce2-tv (6666)' )
insert into stage.test values ('mumbai metropolitan region (356002)')
insert into stage.test values ('')

Tried this query which is not working as expected

select isnull(SUBSTRING([geo_code],CHARINDEX('(',[geo_code ])+1 ,CHARINDEX(')',[geo_code ])-CHARINDEX('(',[geo_code ])-1),'')  as [geo_code ]  as geo_code 
 from stage.test

Expected output
686
76008
6666
356022
null or blank
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to get only numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: you may could take a look to REGEXP_SUBSTR https://way2tutorial.com/sql/sql-regexp_substr-function.php

Comment: No, i have null values in the column so that wont work.Thanks

Comment: @Processor This is SQL Server, not MySQL or Oracle.  They're completely different products.

Comment: @user15132810 Just use that question and include `ISNULL(val, '')` to account for the NULLs in your data

Comment: The answers to your previous question show how to get numbers, they just use it to exclude them, so reverse the logic to include them.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a `PATINDEX` gives that extra OOMPH over a `CHARINDEX`

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING([geo_code]
>                  , PATINDEX('%([0-9]%',[geo_code])+1
>                  , PATINDEX('%[0-9])%',[geo_code]) 
>                  - PATINDEX('%([0-9]%',[geo_code])
>                  ) AS geo_num
> FROM test;
> ```

> | geo_num |
> | --- |
> | 686 |
> | 76008 |
> | 6666 |
> | 356002 |
> |  |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8cb3102872ead363be0a286822cc32f2)*