# How do I remove any text from string SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-cleaning

I have a column:

```
| Duration  |
| --------  |
| 32 minutes|
| 27minutes |
| 20 mins   |
| 15        |
```

I want to remove the text so that only the numbers remain, but as the text is varied I'm at a loss how to do so. I've reviewed multiple solutions and none seem to accomplish the job in an elegant way.

I had another column that was distance, and every row contained 'km' at the end so I was able to use replace.

```
UPDATE runner_orders
SET distance = REPLACE(distance,'km','')
```

I tried doing the same but using a wildcard, this didn't work.

```
UPDATE runner_orders
SET duration = REPLACE(duration, 'min%','')
```

Any input is well appreciated.

Comment: You can use the function translate and replace as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with **CAST**

```
UPDATE runner_orders SET duration = CAST(duration as INT);
```