# Looking to display hierarchy of org units in (parent > child) order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

We're running the below query to output an ID alongside the hierarchy of the table.
Looking to have the values displayed from highest level in the tree to lowest and this is not currently happening.
e.g We want ( Parent > child) rather than (child > parent)
Can the below query be amended to achieve this?
Our table structure is (id, name, parent_id) with the root having a parent_id = null

```
with parents as     
(     
  select ID, parent_ID, name    
  from tblorgunit   
  where parent_ID is not null   
  union all   
  select p.ID,  tblorgunit.parent_ID, tblorgunit.name   
  from parents p   
    inner join tblorgunit on p.parent_ID = tblorgunit.ID    
      and tblorgunit.parent_ID is not null   
      and tblorgunit.ID <> tblorgunit.parent_ID   
)   
select id, name   
  , parents = '(' + stuff   
    (  
      (  
        select ', ' + p.name  
        from parents p   
        where tblorgunit.ID = p.ID  
        for xml path('')  
      ), 1, 2, ''  
    ) + ')'   
from tblorgunit
```

Edit:
When running the below suggested query we encountered an error. Please see link.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e12a/1

What we are looking to see is the following

```
Level 1
Level 1 > Level 2a
Level 1 > Level 2b
Level 1 > Level 2a > Level 3a
Level 1 > Level 2a > Level 3a > Level 4a
```

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the missing `recursive` keyword and the non-standard column aliasing using  `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly (and I'm not sure that I do), I think this might be the solution...

```
with parents as     
(     
  select tblorgunit.ID,  tblorgunit.parent_ID, tblorgunit.name   
  from parents p   
    inner join tblorgunit on p.parent_ID = tblorgunit.ID    
      and tblorgunit.parent_ID is not null   
      and tblorgunit.ID <> tblorgunit.parent_ID   
  union all   
  select ID, parent_ID, name    
  from tblorgunit   
  where parent_ID is not null   
)   
select id, name   
  , parents = '(' + stuff   
    (  
      (  
        select ', ' + p.name  
        from parents p   
        where tblorgunit.ID = p.ID
        and tblorgunit.parent_ID = p.Parent_ID
        for xml path('')  
      ), 1, 2, ''  
    ) + ')'   
from tblorgunit
```

I'm trying to convert from your SQL to an example that works for me, so forgive me if there are any errors...

This gives output similar to this:
1    OrgUnit1    (ParentOrg1, OrgUnit1)
2    OrgUnit2    (ParentOrg1, OrgUnit2)
3    OrgUnit3    (ParentOrg2, OrgUnit3)

Is this what you are after? If not, please provide an example of the output you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Edited original post to explain in more detail what we're after. Also tried the code suggested but got an error.

Comment: Ah, yes, I misunderstood your question. In this answer, I was assuming two physical tables, one called tblorgunit, and the other called parents. But I see from your updates that you have one table that is called recursively. I'll check out your sqlfiddle link and see what I can do...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... In short, you were trying to do the recursion on the outer query when what you wanted to do was recursion on the inner query (in the child area).

```
;WITH parents
AS
(
  SELECT parent.ID, parent.parent_Id, parent.name
  FROM tblorgunit parent
  WHERE parent.parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT child.ID, child.parent_Id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), p.name + ' > ' + child.name)
  FROM tblOrgUnit child
  INNER JOIN parents p ON child.parent_Id = p.ID
  WHERE child.parent_id IS NOT NULL  
)
SELECT * FROM parents
```

For a discussion about why the CONVERT was used, view [this StackOverflow item...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838276/cte-error-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part)

And [here is the updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6639a/1/0).