# CTE triggers casting error from anchor and recursive part

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a CTE as follows which is actually to find all workitems and their parents from VSTS data.

```
;with cte(wtype,id,parent,title,ptype,WILevel,ParentTitle) as
(
select WorkItemType,wi_id,parent,title,ParentType,0 as WILevel,'' as ParentTitle from tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems where Parent is null and state<>'Removed'
union all
select WorkItemType,wi_id,W.parent,W.title,ParentType=t2.wtype,(t2.WILevel+1) as WILevel, t2.title as ParentTitle  from tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems W inner join cte t2 on t2.id=W.Parent where state<>'Removed'
)

select * from cte where WILevel=0;
```

But Im getting the casting error as below.

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ParentTitle" of recursive query "cte".

I didnt understand the issue since the title field is just varchar type. SO why the Type Mismatch?

Comment: What is the type of column `tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems.title`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTE error: “Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838276/cte-error-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my own admission, I searched for your error message and discovered [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838276/cte-error-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part) which discusses a similar problem.

The trick here is that even though both your columns are text, they are not the same type of text (e.g. width, etc.).

Assuming the `tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems.title` column is `varchar(50)`, you could resolve this error by casting the empty string also to `varchar(50)`, e.g.

```
WITH cte (wtype,id,parent,title,ptype,WILevel,ParentTitle) AS (
    SELECT ..., CAST('' AS varchar(50)) AS ParentTitle
    FROM tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems
    WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ..., t2.title
    FROM tbl_VSTS_AllWorkItems
    WHERE ...
)
```

Side note: You only need to use aliases in the very first select in a union query.  In fact, aliases in subsequent portions of the union will just be ignored.

Comment: Since column names are supplied in the CTE's declaration on the first line, aliases are actually also unnecessary in the anchor part. ;)

Comment: Perfect!!! That was the reason.. I casted the title column like this and it worked great..
'' as ParentTitle into cast('' as varchar(100)) as ParentTitle

Answer (score 2):

In the first part of the `union all`, I think you want to be explicit as you create `'' as ParentTitle` so that it is actually the type of column.  For example `convert(varchar(30), null) as ParentTitle`.