# Error in this CTE recursive query: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am having this error:

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Calculated_partnum" of recursive query "Anchor"

From this code shown here:

```
with [Anchor] as 
(
    select 
        [Part].[Company] as [Part_Company],
        [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum],
        (1) as [Calculated_level],
        null as [Calculated_partnum]
    from 
        Part as Part
    inner join  
        PartMtl as PartMtl on Part.Company = PartMtl.Company
                           and Part.PartNum = PartMtl.PartNum

    union all

    select 
        [Anchor].[Part_Company],
        [Part1].[PartNum] as [Part1_PartNum],
        (Anchor.Calculated_Level + 1) as [Calculated_NLevel],
        [Anchor].[Part_PartNum] as [Part_PartNum]
    from   
        Anchor as Anchor
    inner join 
        PartMtl as PartMtl1 on Anchor.Part_Company = PartMtl1.Company
                            and Anchor.Part_PartNum = PartMtl1.PartNum
    inner join 
        Part as Part1 on Part1.Company = PartMtl1.Company
                      and Part1.PartNum = PartMtl1.MtlPartNum
)
select 
    [Anchor1].[Part_Company] as [Part_Company],
    [Anchor1].[Part_PartNum] as [Part_PartNum],
    [Anchor1].[Calculated_level] as [Calculated_level],
    [Anchor1].[Calculated_partnum] as [Calculated_partnum]
from  
    Anchor as Anchor1
```

Comment: Keep the column name same in either part of UNION ALL

Comment: I am not sure, but I would think having null as the value in the first half could cause issues. I'm not sure what type MSSQL presumes a bare null to be. The error message would suggest as much. Have you tried CASTing the null to the needed type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838276/cte-error-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part

Comment: I agree that casting the NULL to match the type of whatever `[part].[partnum]` would probably solve this.

Comment: The aliases of columns in the second dataset onwards are ignored in a `UNION( ALL)` @mkRabbani . `SELECT 1 AS one UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS two;` would return a column called `one`;